# splitWith function for splitting a list doesn't seem optimal

Tags: haskell

As an exercise from RWH, I needed to write a function that splits a list every time the predicate is false (`words` == `splitWith (== ' ')` for strings):

```
splitWith :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitWith _ [] = []
splitWith p xs
    | null pre = splitWith p post'
    | otherwise = pre : splitWith p post'
    where
        (pre, post) = break p xs
        post' = if null post then [] else tail post
```

My concern is the `if`..`then`..`else` chain; it seems "forced". I have to make sure that post isn't null, or it will crash on the call to tail.

Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can gin up a safe version of `tail` lickety-split by using `drop 1`.

Comment: Seriously -_-. I've actually used that before. Thank you; that solves it nicely.